# How to run same logic in parallel across multiple subsets of the same data in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a dataset, let's call it `data1`.

`data1` can be segmented into subsets using a variable `store_number`.

Now for each subset by `store_number` I want to run the same logic, say finding the `total sales amount`.

Is it possible to run this logic across all the stores `in parallel in python`? In my current set up I have put this as a `for loop`, which means that `store_number 2` will occur only after `store_number 1` and so on, which leads to a very slow process. I am wondering if `store_number 1` and `store_number 2` can run in `parallel` at the same time.

Note: The actual logic is a little more complicated than `group by` and a simple `sum` therefore, the need for a `for loop`.

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Do you have any example you could share?

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example)., [https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#examples).

Answer (score 0):

If your calculation is a CPU-bound task, you should look at using [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to apply your function to each subset using separate CPU cores.

If your task is IO-bound (e.g. it involves DB queries), you should check out the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) which will run over each subset in its own thread.